# A meta-build solution managing multiple projects

Tags: deployment, build, installation, environment, build-system

I'm looking for an advice about the software that did not catch my eye during a few days of searches.

Is there any software solution for deployment of multiple projects at once that operates at the level of source-building package manager (like [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports), [portages](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage), or [nix](https://nixos.org/nix/)), but could be resided locally?

As for details, we have few loosely connected software projects with the following traits:

- Projects are written mostly on C/C ++ and Python, but more languages are represented as a minor mixture (Haskell, Rust, Perl)
- Projects are grouped together within [git superprojects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Submodules_and_Superprojects) with certain build/deployment presets carefully tuned for particular environments (and adapted for particular purposes by subset of boolean-like options)
- We have already done with well-elaborated CMake build scripts for C++ projects that do support options, build configurations, exporting targets, and so on. It would be expensive to switch from it now.
- We are forced to deal with various Linux distributions (from Gentoo and Ubuntu to Debian and CentOS).

We need an unifying build&deployment tool for various environments. The CMake does not integrate well with non-compiling languages (e.g. does not natively support local Python installations via virtualenv).

Instead of changing the things we already developed, I would like to use them in the manner the OS package manager does. For my vision, it should be something pretty similar to the so-called [meta-build tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software#Meta-build_tools). In fact, the Gentoo Portages are pretty close:

- Easy customization with simple boolean options (useflags, profiles)
- Delegation of the building procedures to the reliable and customizable tools designed and well-tested especially for this purpose (CMake, autotools, Bazel, etc.)
- Offers an ability to change the target compiler installation and specify the building process in a clear declarative way with a standardized instructions set.
  Portages can not be ran locally, though (and have other unrelated flaws).

I have to become very confident before switching the whole build system to something like [Meson](http://mesonbuild.com/) or [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) or whatever else I could find up to the moment.

#### Update

To be more specific, I could refer to what we have done up to the moment. The [one](https://gitlab.cern.ch/P348/NA64-meta) of the superprojects we're maintaining deals with particular scientific experiment:

- All the sub-projects are [listed](https://gitlab.cern.ch/P348/NA64-meta/tree/master/sources) as git submodules
- A simple [BASH-script](https://gitlab.cern.ch/P348/NA64-meta/blob/master/presets.build/functions.ish) maintaining the entire build-install-deploy lifecycle
- The presets referring particular settings for a concrete environment are represented as [BASH sources](https://gitlab.cern.ch/P348/NA64-meta/tree/master/presets.build/byHosts/_lxplus/_any) and are included by this maintaining shell script.

As few days more had come with no result, I coming up with intention to write my own solution based on experience we already gained due to these shell scripting activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a similar task [Bob](https://bobbuildtool.github.io/) was developed some time ago. If you still need a build system it might be worth a look. There are some small tutorials available as well as a complex basement example build a linux from scratch.

Basically it is just a environment for a controlled execution of bash scripts with dependency and variant handling, CI integration, IDE support,..

Comment: Thank you, Ralf. I've seen this tool during my survey. Indeed, it appears to be the proper tool for this problem. However, the official GitHub page warns that project is currently archieved. May be you know the reason why maintainers stopped its development? In particular, did the GAP development team found something superseeding instead?

Comment: I know the maintainer and he is still active developing and maintaining the tool. Looking at [GitHub](https://github.com/BobBuildTool/bob/) I can't find this warning?

Comment: Pardon, I was confused by the [one](https://github.com/gap-system/bob)  maintained by GAP team. Evidently, it was related to GAP _only_.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sparrow](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrow) - Linux scripting platform, it supports projects hierarchy and tasks - configurable scripts, where configuration is made in declarative way in Yaml, Json formats. This hopefully might address many if not all the needs you've mentioned here.

Disclosure - I am the tool author.

Comment: Thank you for this nice suggestion, Alexey.
Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but this systems seems to be rather a scenario scheduling tool, while my use case implies an elaborated dependency management based on volatile conditions graph. Indeed, your solution could cover the problem, but with essential additional scripting effort which would be comparable to the development a dedicated tool from scratch.

Comment: HI Crank! Sparrow acts as Linux scripting platform with many batteries included. It seems to me if you need some meta build tool Sparrow might be interesting as Sparrow is able to adopt to any existed systems. In Sparrow you create high or low level scenarios ( using Bash, Ruby, Python or Perl ) and then you manage such a scenarios in very flexible way - declaring tasks ( scenarios and configurations in YAML/JSON/Config::General format). You can also distribute scenarios as SparrowHub plugins or store them in JSON format at SCM.  You can even run scenarios remotely by ssh using Sparrowdo tool.

Comment: _Indeed, your solution could cover the problem, but with essential additional scripting effort which would be comparable to the development a dedicated tool from scratch_

of course some coding is required, however I am not sure how much, without having all the details, however I am happy to collaborate, we may discuss details if you want ...